# SPSS if condition

Tags: spss

I need your help to perform a certain operation in SPSS. I have two questions. If the answer to the first question is "Yes", then the program should continue to the second question, otherwise not.

Can you give me the steps? I tried to search but came up empty-handed.

Answer (score 1):

Just clean var2 if some condition:

```
if var1=2 var2=$sysmis.
```